# POWER BI visualizations - multiple columns with different status

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, measure, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have one report that contain multiple columns (Status 1 to status 7) with different status (Okay, Not Okay, Completed and Not completed),  each columns has different count with different status.

[image]

**Example;** Status 1 has two different status which is "Okay" and "Not Okay", "Okay" count has 6039 and "Not okay" count has 13.

I summarised the data of each status for your reference. (Data prepared manually)

[image]

At the moment I am using 7 different charts, is there any way I can achieve my result all of them in one chart? Can you please suggested the best way to achieve the result in Power BI visualizations?
Herewith attached the excel file for your additional reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cmuh32sit97rr1/POWER%20BI-VISUAL.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Hi. any advise please on this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice to see you tagged me in LinkedIn referring this question link for my input. I am really glad for that.

I go thorough your requirement and my felling this below approach will be better (my feeling) for presentation for the data you wants present to the end user.

[image]

**Now**, if you are agree with me, one transformation in **Power Query Editor** and a single **Measure** will serve your purpose. Go to **Power Query Editor** and apply **Unpivot Other Colum** by selecting **ITEM** column as shown below-

[image]

The output will be as below-

[image]

Now get back to report and create this below **Measure**-

```
status_count = COUNT(DATA[ITEM])
```

**Finally** add a **Matrix** and configure as below-

[image]

Final output is shown in the first image.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time and effort and it's good idea. I like your solutions. Those seven status columns are created based on the DAX measure therefore it won't be appear in the table and I can't use the unpivot option here. I there any alternative option? Could you please advise.

Comment: I will try to change my data maybe it's easy way to achieve my end result. Thank you.